# How to adding a where condition to SQL Server Merge statement for Deletes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge-statement

```
MERGE  DestinationTable AS D 
USING @SourceTable AS S
ON D.Alternate_ID = S._ID

WHEN MATCHED AND
(
       D.Candidate_ID <> S.Candidate_ID  OR  ISNULL(D.Vacancy_ID,'') <> S.Vacancy_ID   
)
THEN
UPDATE SET  
    D.FName = S.FName,
    D.Department = S.Department,

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT  
(
    Alternate_ID,
    FName,
    Department
 ) 
  VALUES 
  (
    S.ID,
    S.FName,
    S.Department  
  ) 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
 --How to add a where clause to the delete statement here
 THEN  DELETE; --E.g WHERE  D.Department <> 'HR'
```

I'm using the Merge Statement above to delete records in the DestinationTable if they have been removed from source

Does any one know how a can add a WHERE condition to the Delete statement?. I want to only delete from destination where ColA is equal to a particular constant string.

Comment: According to http://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/30/the-merge-statement-doesnt-have-a-where-clause/, you can add to the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND D.Department <> 'HR' THEN DELETE

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for `MERGE`.

```
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
    THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
```

Here is the documentation applied to the `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` portion of your query (assuming CoIA is a column in the destination table):

```
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND D.CoIA = 'YourValue' THEN
DELETE;
```

However, be sure to note the following:

> The MERGE statement can have at most two WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
>   clauses. If two clauses are specified, then the first clause must be
>   accompanied by an AND < clause_search_condition > clause. For any given
>   row, the second WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE clause is only applied if
>   the first is not. If there are two WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE clauses,
>   then one must specify an UPDATE action and one must specify a DELETE
>   action. **Only columns from the target table can be referenced in
>   < clause_search_condition >**.